# how to convert python None (or numpy.nan) when inserting into sql server using jdbc via pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pyspark, jdbc, databricks

I have a problem inserting data to an existing sql server table.
I use the command:

```py
df_spark.write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table='scd.'+table_name, mode='append' ,properties=connectionProperties)
```

to append data to the table, df_spark being a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` object.

However, one column at the receiving table is of type datetime2 and is allowed to have nulls, but how do I send in data that SQL server will interpret as `NULL`?

What I have done:

I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [scd].[test]([Id] INT,
                          [InsertDatetime] datetime2 NULL)
```

When trying to append data I run in to the following problems:

```py
a = {
    'Id':[1, 2],
    'InsertDatetime':['2022-11-24T09:56:25.7228705', None]
}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(a)
table_name = test
df_spark.write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table='scd.'+table_name, mode='append'    ,properties=connectionProperties)
```

Gives error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for void

```py
a = {
    'Id':[1, 2],
    'InsertDatetime':['2022-11-24T09:56:25.7228705', np.nan]
}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(a)
table_name = test
df_spark.write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table='scd.'+table_name, mode='append' ,properties=connectionProperties)
```

Gives error:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Operand type clash: float is incompatible with datetime2